# SqlTransaction with UPDLOCK

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

So I have a `patientinfo` table where I'm inserting a patient with a click of a `button`.

That same button, generates the ID of the patient but for some reason, if I run a timer to execute this code from 5 apps at the exact same time, only one will go through, while the other ones will fail. Although I have tried to use `ROWlock` in this query, `Updlock`, and even `Tablockx`.

Any thoughts on what could be causing that? There are no errors aside from the `Primary key error` when the insertion fails because I'm inserting the same generated ID.

```
    Private Function GetNextPatientId(labID As String) As String
    Dim connectionString As String = My.Settings.PatientsConnectionString
    Dim result As String = ""

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        connection.Open()

        Dim retryCount As Integer = 0
        Dim maxRetries As Integer = 3
        Dim delayMilliseconds As Integer = 400

        Using transaction As SqlTransaction = connection.BeginTransaction()
            While retryCount < maxRetries
                Try
                    Dim queryString As String = "
                    BEGIN TRAN
                    DECLARE @nextPatientId AS VARCHAR(12);

                    SELECT TOP 1 @nextPatientId = (CAST(SUBSTRING(PatientID, 3, 12) AS BIGINT) + 1)
                    FROM patientinfo WITH (UPDLOCK)
                    WHERE SUBSTRING(patientid, 1, 2) = @labID
                    ORDER BY SUBSTRING(PatientID, 3, 12) DESC;

                    IF @nextPatientId IS NULL
                        SET @nextPatientId = '01';

                    SELECT @nextPatientId AS nextPatientIdValue;
                    COMMIT TRAN;"

                    Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection, transaction)
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@labID", labID)

                    Dim nextPatientIdValue As String = ""
                    Using reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                        If reader.Read() Then
                            nextPatientIdValue = Convert.ToString(reader("nextPatientIdValue"))
                        End If
                    End Using

                    result = nextPatientIdValue

                    Exit While
                Catch ex As SqlException When ex.Number = 1205 AndAlso retryCount < maxRetries
                    retryCount += 1
                    Threading.Thread.Sleep(delayMilliseconds)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    transaction.Rollback()
                    Throw
                End Try
            End While

            transaction.Commit()
        End Using
    End Using

    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: I would recommend just using `IDENTITY` instead of this scheme but `WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)` might work. As it will lock the range and hold the lock until the end of the transaction

Comment: I'll give it a try. Any reason on why the combination you mentioned would work but TABLOCKX wouldn't?

Comment: `TABLOCKX` doesn't mention that the locks will be held until the end of the transaction and presumably they aren't from the behaviour you describe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-ver16#tablockx

Comment: Okay so using updlock holdlock didn't really do the trick.

I have a question though. It should be totally fine that the insert and SELECT are not in the same query. Correct?

Comment: You should put your SELECT generating nextPatientIdValue and INSERT in `patientinfo` inside a common transaction for the UPDLOCK to have any effect. Currently second app waits only until COMMIT is executed by the first app and gets the same MAX(PatientID) from `patientinfo` table as the first app has not INSERTed anything there yet.

Comment: Ah I completely missed that the `BEGIN TRAN .... COMMIT` doesn't even include an `INSERT`! - so yeah that won't work

Comment: Where is the `INSERT` here I don't see it? There are other strange things: `Catch ... transaction.Rollback` is unnecessary as the `Using` will do that. You don't need a doubly nested transaction, either use a client-side transaction or a server-side one (preferably the latter). To retrieve one value you don't need a reader, just use `command.ExecuteScalar`. Storing multiple pieces of information in a single column (and having to convert and sort by that) is a really bad idea, it cannot use indexing and will therefore end up with huge scans and blocking/deadlock issues.